# Return to start of loop java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

This is a program that lets the user enter the loan amount and loan period in number of years and displays the monthly and total payments for each interest rate starting from 5% to 8%, with an increment of 1/8.

I may have over-indulged myself here as I'm pretty new to programming, but I'm in too deep and want to figure this out.

With my current code the first line outputs correctly, displaying the rate, total and monthly. However, after that the code just continues to output the inner most loop. I need to return to the start of the loop. It would greatly be appreciated if you could point me in the right direction.

P.S. I am aware that my padding isn't in place. My biggest concern is getting the algorithm down on "paper" first, and then worrying about the beauty of it.

```
package loancalc194;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoanCalc194 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 //LOAN CALCULATOR 
 //user enters loan AMOUNT, loan PERIOD(years), 
 //output displays MONTHLY and TOTAL payments
 //^displayed per 1/8 increment from 5-8% interest

 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

 //prompt user
 //retrieve loan amount and period
 System.out.print("Please enter the loan amount: ");   
 double amount = in.nextDouble();   
 System.out.print("Please enter the loan period (years): ");
 int period = in.nextInt();

 //INTEREST LOOP///////////////////////////////////////////////////

 double interest = .05000;
 double inc = 0.00125;
 interest = interest + inc;
 double monthly = 0;
 double total = 0;

 System.out.println("Interest Rate\t\t\tTotal Payment\tMonthly Payment");

 while (interest < .08){
     //interest = interest + inc;
     System.out.print(interest + "\t");   

     while (true){ 
        total = (amount * period) + (interest * amount);
        System.out.print("\t" + total + "\t\t");

        while (true) {
            monthly = ((total / period) / 12);
            System.out.println(monthly);
            //interest = interest + inc;
        }
     } 
 }
```

Comment: You need a break condition for your other 2 loops.

Comment: What are these loops even supposed to be doing, you are just endlessly calculating the same values...?

Comment: Why do you even wrap those lines in loops? Doesn't make any sense

Comment: The appropriate time to worry about the indentation of your code should be **before** you are showing your code to other people and asking them to try and read it.

Comment: as a side note: *use proper JavaDoc instead of those clumsy comments*

Answer (score 0):

One loop should be enough for what you want.

Your two `while(true)` loops do nothing else than looping on the same values forever.

In the following code, the *interest* gets incremented and the new calculations computed at each loop until *interest* reaches your max value, this is probably what you need.

```
 double interest = .05000;
 double inc = 0.00125;
 double monthly = 0;
 double total = 0;

 while (interest < .08){

     System.out.print(interest + "\t");   

     total = (amount * period) + (interest * amount);
     System.out.print("\t" + total + "\t\t");

     monthly = ((total / period) / 12);
     System.out.println(monthly);

     interest = interest + inc;

 }
```

Comment: At least explain your answer, dumping code for rep does not help anyone learn from their mistakes